# Is there a way to style the active bookmark element?

Tags: html, css

I have a PHP page which generates a table with rows like this:

```html
<tr id="someNumber"> <td> Hello world </td> </tr>
```

**`someNumber` is literally some number.**

Now if the link to this page is something like *`xyz.com/tablePage#someNumber`*

Is there a way to use **just** CSS selectors to style the row which has the bookmark "**`someNumber`**" ?

As it's a PHP script I know that I can check while generating the page if the someNumber value in the URL matches with the row's `someNumber` and add a class to it. However i'm looking for a way to style using CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) css pseudo-class to style the element with an id matching the url hash fragment

```
:target {
  background: green;
}
```

will give your table row a green background

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible. You could use PHP (like you said) to add a class. Something like:

```
<?= ($_GET['somenumber'] ?: "") == $variable ? "active" : "" =?>
```

The `$_GET['somenumber'] ?: ""` section checks if somenumber is set, and otherwise replaces it with "". Then it checks if it is the same as the variable you set, and if it is it prints 'active', or whatever css class you want.